# Проблемы с установкой Visual Studio 2017 на Windows 7

Tags: windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Не устанавливается *VisualStudio* из-за D3DCOMPILLER_47.dll. Я даже искала во многих источниках решение этой проблемы, в том числе установила DirectX, но ничего не сработало. Так и выдает такое же окно:

[image: Нет установки]

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/uk-ua/help/4019990/update-for-the-d3dcompiler-47-dll-component-on-windows

Comment: Вы пробовали установить библиотеку напрямую, как это описано здесь http://internetaccessmonitor.ru/3353-d3dcompiler_47_dll.html ?

Comment: Да, и именно так пробовала. Не помогает.

Answer (score 2):

Качаем http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB4019990 под свою версию

С помощью [7-zip](http://7-zip.org) распаковываем kb. Можно через `wusa /extract`

В cmd (пример для win7-64):

```
dism /Online /Add-Package /NoRestart /PackagePath:<полный, относительный или сетевой путь до>\Windows6.1-KB4019990-x64.cab
```

Ссылки на источники, для тех, у кого паранойя:

https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/help/4019990/update-for-the-d3dcompiler-47-dll-component-on-windows

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askcore/2011/02/15/how-to-use-dism-to-install-a-hotfix-from-within-windows/

https://www.google.ru/search?q=d3dcompiler_47.dll&oq=d3dcompiler_47.dll&aqs=chrome..69i57.11070j0j1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: спасибо. Надеюсь после этих установок, компьютер выживет.

Comment: @Исмира, добавил ссылок. 2 из них - официальные "от разработчика".

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: @Исмира, помогло?

Comment: Еще не устанавливала. Но установлю обязательно. По любому же нужен VisualStudio.