# Программа требует обновлений KB303513 и KB3033929. Но они не устанавливаются

Tags: windows

**OS:** Win7

Хочу установить EDIUS 7 но не могу.
Инсталятор выдает, что нужны два обновления сыстемы. KB3033929 + KB303513. Попытка установить вызывает сообщение, что они уже установлены. В списке установленных обновления их нету.

Comment: у майкрософта бывают кумулятивные обновления. Такое обновление может снести несколько предыдущих и поставиться вместо. И формально обновление есть, а глупый инсталлер его не видет. Я бы распаковал инсталлятор и посмотрел что там и как.

Comment: Я всё это понимаю. Но как заставить поставиться эту программу?

Comment: а может ее не нужно ставить? Но я бы попробовал поискать portable версию

Comment: Это EDIUS 7. Portable нету. А если бы и было... Были бы проблемы при установке расширений в виде фильтров.

Comment: А через `dism` тоже не пашет?

Comment: @donRumata, не знаю, что такое dism.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/779763/191416 всё то же самое, только kb твои.

Answer (score 1):

Ну что же. Опять отвечаю на свой вопрос. Может кому пригодится.

Конкретно для EDIUS 7, нужно запустить инсталятор с опцией **/CHECKIGNORE**

http://www.ediusworld.com/en/support/faq/cat120/cat3_778.html

Что же касается других программ, то предполагается, что в для них тоже существует параметр командной строки, который отменяет проверку.